# Why aren't the notes not appending when I click on the "p" tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image]

```
 $(document).on("click", "p", function() {
    $("#notes").empty();
    alert("hello");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/articles/" + id
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);

        $("#notes").append("<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>");
        $("#notes").append("<input id='titleinput' name='title' >");
        $("#notes").append("<textarea id='bodyinput' name='body'></textarea>");
        $("#notes").append("<button data-id='" + data._id + "' id='savenote'>Save Note</button>");

        if (data.note) {
            $("#titleinput").val(data.note.title);
            $("#bodyinput").val(data.note.body);
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on a "p" tag, the notes inputs should pop up to the right of the text, but they do not. I do not know what I am doing wrong that is keeping them from showing up. The alert pops ups, so the tag is okay. But why are the notes not coming?

Comment: There's no alert in the code, where is that coming from?

Comment: Post your HTML.

Comment: @Barmar sorry that was another code for the solution. I just posted mine with the alert

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the response to be parsed as JSON. Does the server send `Content-type: application/json` header? If not, you need `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: link: "https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/08/opinion/epa-climate-environment-trump.html"
summary: "↵                        Scientists issued a new alarm on the devastating impacts of continued burning of fossil fuels. But the Trump E.P.A. keeps propping up coal.                                             "
title: "Coal is Killing the Planet. Trump Loves It."
__v: 0
_id: "5bbc1526fed2a737d46d22bb"
__proto__: Object

Comment: There aren't any errors

Comment: Is `#notes` hidden? Maybe you need `$("#notes").show();`